# UTF-8 input on UART

Tags: c, utf-8, avr, stdio, uart

Based on [Mika Tuupola's tutorial](http://www.appelsiini.net/2011/simple-usart-with-avr-libc) I am trying to use serial input from the UART as `stdin`. The lowlevel UART communication code is as follows:

```
#ifndef BAUD
#define BAUD 9600
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <util/setbaud.h>

void uart_init ()
{
    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;

#if USE_2X
    UCSR0A |= _BV(U2X0);
#else
    UCSR0A &= ~(_BV(U2X0));
#endif

    UCSR0C = _BV(UCSZ01) | _BV(UCSZ00);
    UCSR0B = _BV(RXEN0) | _BV(TXEN0);
}

void uart_putchar (char c)
{
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = c;
}

char uart_getchar ()
{
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, RXC0);
    return UDR0;
}
```

The next layer exposes `uart_getchar` and `uart_putchar` as stream handler-compatible functions:

```
int uart_putchar_s (char c, FILE *stream)
{
    if (c == '\n')
        uart_putchar('\r');
    uart_putchar(c);
    return 0;
}

int uart_getchar_s (FILE *stream)
{
    return uart_getchar();
}

FILE uart_output = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar_s, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
FILE uart_input =  FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(NULL, uart_getchar_s, _FDEV_SETUP_READ);

void uart_init_stdio()
{
    stdout = &uart_output;
    stdin  = &uart_input;
}
```

and then my `main` just reads in a character and prints it back out. It deliberately uses `printf` so that the output is always via the `stdout` stream abstraction.

```
int main ()
{
    uart_init();
    uart_init_stdio();

    for (;;)
    {
        char c = uart_getchar();
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

If I connect to this from a UTF-8 serial terminal, and type in e.g. `á`, I correctly see that I get back the two bytes representing `á` in UTF-8: local echo shows that my terminal sends the bytes `C3 A1`, and these are the same two bytes I get back. So far, so good.

However, if I then change `main` to use `getchar()` instead of `uart_getchar()` (i.e. if I go through the `stdin` stream abstraction for the input), then after sending the same `C3 A1` bytes, all I get back is `FF FF`. Why is that? Is there something more going on here then just sending and receiving individual bytes that just happen to encode single glyphs when looked at through the lens of UTF-8?

Comment: On small MCUs, using the stdlib streams is most times a bad idea. It is larger, and slow. Just write a simple library with specialised input/output functions.

Comment: Use a debugger to track the flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that `uart_getchar()` returns a "char", which is signed on your platform.
Characters > 0x7f are therefore interpreted as negative return value and thus, the stdio-layer returns `EOF`, which is -1 (0xFF if interpreted unsigned) on your platform.

Try declaring `uart_getchar()` as returning "int":

```
int uart_getchar ()
{
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, RXC0);
    return (unsigned char) UDR0;
}
```

Comment: You did: "Characters > 0x7f are therefore interpreted as negative return value" Is wrong. Also "thus, the stdio-layer returns EOF". `EOF` is a **specific** negative value. It is often, but not necessarily `-1`.

Comment: No, this refered to _his_ case, where this obviously happened.

Comment: I still do not get what should be wrong with EOF. If uart_getchar() returns a negative value (whatever value is irrelevant), getchar() will return EOF. What's the issue with that?

Comment: It's still not quite clear what exactly happens in `getchar`. While I agree your snippet would be the correct way, the problem is in `getchar`. We miss the interface definition of the function from `getchar`/stdlib implementation.

Comment: However, main problem are the two missleading statements.

Comment: I still do not see, where the second statement (EOF) would be misleading, please elaborate. I never wrote that EOF == -1

Comment: Finally: You implied it: OP sees `0xFF` output, you write "thus, the stdio-layer returns EOF". How do you know that is `EOF`?

Comment: Because there is no other possibility, of course. What else could it be?

Comment: Just add something this is specific to OPs code. I'll remove the DV then. Remember tanswers will be read by others, too, so they should make clear which is generally applicable and which is specific.

Comment: I can live with that:-) (Btw: `0xFF` is still only the lower 8 bits of the value, so _strictly_ speaking `EOF` still cann differ. But that would be too nitpicky - even for me ;-)